# roll join of two non-overlapping `data.table`s

Tags: r, data.table

Let's have two non-overlapping data.tables and do a rolling join:

```
library(data.table)
P = data.table(id=c("a","a"), t=c(1,4), txn=c(0, 0),key=c("id", "t"))
TX = data.table(id=c("a"), t=c(3), txn=c(1111),key=c("id", "t")) # note the index t = 3 falling in the gap of P
P[TX, txn:=i.txn, roll=TRUE]
P
#    id t  txn
# 1:  a 1 1111
# 2:  a 4    0
```

Why is `txn` rolled to the *previous* available index (`t=1`), when with `roll>0` I would expect it to be rolled to the *next* available one (`t=4`)?

```
P # expected
#    id t  txn
# 1:  a 1    0
# 2:  a 4 1111
```

Comment: What behavior are you trying to get? or you're ok with this and just asking why it happens?

Comment: @smci, he's shown the expected output at the bottom of the post.

Comment: @Arun: I already read what he wrote. He didn't say if he actually **wanted** it or was just asking out of curiosity. Nowhere did he say what he wants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `?data.table` (under `roll` argument):

> If `roll=TRUE` and `i`'s row matches to all but the last `x` join column, and its value in the last `i` join column falls in a gap (including after the last observation in `x` for that group), *then the prevailing value in x is rolled forward.*

Here, the value t=3, from `TX` (= i) falls in a gap, between t=1 and t=4 from `P`. And therefore the match is with the *prevailing value* in `P` (= x) is t=1, and the corresponding row is the first row. You can find it out by doing:

```
P[TX, which=TRUE, roll=Inf] ## same as roll=TRUE, LOCF
# [1] 1
```

Instead if we do:

```
P[TX, which=TRUE, roll=-Inf] ## NOCB
# [1] 2
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thank you, it does, returns the result I need: `P[TX, txn:=i.txn, roll=-Inf]` I've tried many combinations, but `roll=-Inf` feels a bit counter-intuitive; given it is `TX` rolling up or down the `P` index grid to find the nearest non-gap position, _positive_ sign in `roll` would hint at movement _down_ the grid; exactly opposite behaviour is the case

Comment: It might be counter-intuitive, if you din't go through the explanation given under `roll` in `?data.table` ;-).